# sort an array("1:40","2:30","6:33") lowest to highest?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am new in PHP I have an array a different format but, I don't know how to sort from lowest to highest
i know the inbuilt function like sort and others too but these are not suitable for me please help if anybody knows, I have this array format

```
$array = array("2:90","8:49","3:77","4:98");
```

and this array needs to sort as

```
8:49,3:77,2:90,4:98
```

sort by right values after symbol (:)

Comment: Okay. Well, PHP has lots of built in sorting functions, and ways to work with strings and convert strings to numbers, so that shouldn't be a problem for you. If it _is_ a problem for you, [explain what you thought would be a good approach, what code you wrote to do that, how that code didn't do what you expected, and what you already tried to make it work](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i was also thinking same but when i am trying inbuilt functions its not sorting correctly

Comment: right, but you've not really finished your post: what is the characteristic to sort on (second number? total number? etc)? And what did _you_ come up with as potential ways to do this - not strictly speaking "in PHP" but what approach would you take, and have you already written code to then do what you're thinking needs to happen here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a custom comparator and use [**usort**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with it:

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b) {
    // Split the value by the ":" delimiter and store each side into variable
    list($a_first, $a_second) = explode(':', $a);
    list($b_first, $b_second) = explode(':', $b);
    // If the second substrings are not equal compare them
    if ($a_second != $b_second) {
      return strcmp($a_second, $b_second);
    }
    // If they are equal compare the values in the first substrings
    return strcmp($a_first, $b_first);
}

$array = array("2:90","1:90","8:49","3:77","4:98");
print "Before sorting:\n";
print_r($array);
usort($array, "cmp");
print "After sorting:\n";
print_r($array);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Before sorting: 
Array
(
    [0] => 2:90
    [1] => 1:90
    [2] => 8:49
    [3] => 3:77
    [4] => 4:98
)
After sorting: 
Array
(
    [0] => 8:49
    [1] => 3:77
    [2] => 1:90
    [3] => 2:90
    [4] => 4:98
)
```

Explanations and links to docs of other functions used:

- **[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** - Split a string by a string.
- **[strcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)** - Binary safe string comparison.

---

A solution to the additional requirement to handle decimals provided in comments of this answer:

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b) {
    // Split the value by the ":" delimiter and store each side into variable
    list($a_first, $a_second) = array_map('floatval', explode(':', $a));
    list($b_first, $b_second) = array_map('floatval', explode(':', $b));
    // If the second substrings are not equal compare them
    if (abs($a_second - $b_second) >= PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON) {
      return $a_second - $b_second;
    }
    // If they are equal compare the values in the first substrings
    return $a_first - $b_first;
}

$array = array("2:90.60","2:95.67","1:95.67","8:49","3:77.66","4:98.30");
print "Before sorting:\n";
print_r($array);
usort($array, "cmp");
print "After sorting:\n";
print_r($array);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Before sorting:
Array
(
    [0] => 2:90.60
    [1] => 2:95.67
    [2] => 1:95.67
    [3] => 8:49
    [4] => 3:77.66
    [5] => 4:98.30
)
After sorting:
Array
(
    [0] => 8:49
    [1] => 3:77.66
    [2] => 2:90.60
    [3] => 1:95.67
    [4] => 2:95.67
    [5] => 4:98.30
)
```

Explanations and links to docs of other functions used:

- **[array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)** - Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays
- [**floatval**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) - Get float value of a variable

Comment: thank you very much for helping but this function is not working with decimal value like array("2:90.60","1:95.67","8:49","3:77.66","4:98.30");